# Logging out of Facebook invalidates offline_access token

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm getting an offline access token like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?scope=offline_access&client_id=MYCLIENTID&redirect_uri=MYREDIRECTURI&client_secret=MYSECRET&code=MYCODE

obviously the MYCLIENTID and stuff have been changed for the sake of this post. Anyway, as soon as the user logs out of facebook, the key seems to no longer be valid. Am I not requesting offline_access properly (there's still an "expires" value on it, should there be if it is actually getting offline access), or is that just how it works?

If it's the latter, how can I get a key that will persist, regardless of if the user logs out of facebook? I'm sure this is possible, because Tweetdeck can still write to Facebook, even though I'm currently logged out.

Answer (score 1):

expires will still be there but should be set to 0.

to make it short, you should store the access token somewhere in a database, and use it.

from this blog, the first script does that: http://cuneytgurcan.wordpress.com/2011/01/07/php-facebook-cronjob-with-offline-access/

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use this URL instead:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=offline_access&client_id=[AppId]&redirect_uri=[redirect_uri]&response_type=token

Once I switched to that, I got an alert about the offline permissions when I logged into Facebook, and the token remains active after logout.